# What does a 'lop-sided board' mean in Charles Dickens' "The Haunted House"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, charles-dickens

Can someone please help me picture the following situation?

> A **lop-sided board** drooped over the garden wall, announcing that it was 'to let on very reasonable terms, well furnished.

<sub>Charles Dickens, [The Haunted House](http://books.google.it/books?id=Bf0aBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=lop-sided%20board%20drooped%20over%20the%20garden%20wall&source=bl&ots=jvsvH1zDV_&sig=Lz1-JKoOOZxgtp3yEDA9OrEklZU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hAR7VNWvFazX7QawjYHgDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=lop-sided%20board%20drooped%20over%20garden%20wall&f=false)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a sign on the garden wall.  The sign reads, "Furnished property for rent, reasonable terms."

[Lopsided](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lopsided) - with one side lower or smaller than the other

[Board](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/board) - a thin, flat, rectangular piece of wood or other stiff material used for various purposes.

[Let](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/let) - allow someone to have the use of (a room or property) in return for regular payments; rent

Comment: a board that says that? can i be 100% sure?

Comment: Yes, I am confident in my interpretation of the quote you provided.

Comment: I agree with Lumberjack. It is a board serving as a sign. "...drooped over a garden wall," could mean hung over the wall or perhaps mounted on top of the wall but sagging.

Comment: Yes, this board is a sign.  You might be thinking that a board must be arbitrarily long to be called a board, and thus is not suitable for a sign, but no it doesn't.  A board could be square.  That being said, if Dickens were writing his stories today, he probably would have been explicit that this was signage.

Answer (score 0):

lopsided = uneven, i.e. hanging or tilted to one side. the type of board referred to was generally a piece of flat wood with the information written/painted on, this in turn would be secured to an upright post to make it easily visible, e.g. above a fence or wall surrounding the property being advertised. If the post wasn't completely upright, the board would appear 'lopsided', and would droop, or hang, over the wall.